# How can I add programs allowed with restricted write18?

Tags: miktex, texlive, shell-escape

By default, TeX is in restricted write18 mode, which means it can only call a select few external programs. How can I edit that list of programs? This would enable me to use packages that need to call other programs than those that are allowed by default without having to sacrifice all of the security of restricted write18.

I am looking for a solution both for MiKTeX and TeX Live.

Answer (score 11):

For TeX Live, issue from the terminal

```
kpsewhich texmf.cnf
```

This should answer

```
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf.cnf
```

(the year can vary). This is the top level `texmf.cnf` and values set here are not overridden by later loaded similar configuration files.

The main `texmf.cnf` file, which sits as `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf` contains

```
shell_escape_commands = \
bibtex,bibtex8,\
extractbb,\
gregorio,\
kpsewhich,\
makeindex,\
repstopdf,\
r-mpost,\
texosquery-jre8,\
```

Check the list, because new versions of TeX Live might change the list.

Now append the list above to the top level `texmf.cnf` file (you need appropriate privileges to edit it) and add in the same way the programs you want to be available in the restricted shell. Carefully note the format: the trailing backslashes avoid adding spaces after commas.

But don't blame me if your system gets damaged by running dangerous programs in the restricted shell escape.

---

You can add one or more programs on the fly when calling `pdflatex` (or other engine) from the command line by something like (Bash syntax)

```
shell_escape_commands=$(kpsewhich -var-value=shell_escape_commands),ls pdflatex file
```

Here the added program is `ls`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is it possible to _add_ to a variable, like `shell_escape_commands = $shell_escape_commands,ls`? Or do I need to repeat the entire list from the main `texmf.cnf`?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik No, because the main `texmf.cnf` file is read later than the top level one, so the value of `shell_escape_commands` has not yet been set.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I added an alternative way that might interest you.

Comment: That's handy :-) Thanks!

Comment: Note that the exact file locations may be different. For me `kpsewhich` returns `/etc/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf` (empty apart from setting `VARTEXFONTS`), while there are two other files `/usr/share/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf` and `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf` that contain the shell escape settings (both files are exactly equal). Also, the top level file warns that it should not be edited because this may interfere with upgrades, and `/etc/texmf/texmf.d` should be edited instead (or alternatively an extra `.cnf` file should be added with `update-texmf`).